# Scope Issue in Azure Graph Rest API Java

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am new using Azure Graph Rest API Java using [this repo](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java).

My aim is to list all of the users in the AAD tenant

So far I was only able to get to this:

```
List<String> scopes= Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All");
   

    AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(tenantId, subscriptionId, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
    final ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .tenantId(tenantId)
            //.httpClient(client)
            .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
            .build();

    TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, credential);


    GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient =
            GraphServiceClient
                    .builder()
                    .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                    .buildClient();


    UserCollectionPage users = graphClient.users()
            .buildRequest()
            .get();

   for(User user: users.getCurrentPage()){

       System.out.println(user.displayName);
       System.out.println(user.id);
       System.out.println(user.userPrincipalName);

   }
```

However, I run into this error instead:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException:
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException:
> AADSTS1002012: The
> provided value for scope https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All
> openid profile offline_access is not valid. Client credential flows
> must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource
> identifier (application ID URI).

It seems the Scope that I have used is wrong/insufficient, but I am not too sure what should I use the scope with. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is written in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scopes-oidc#client-credentials-grant-flow-and-default) that:

> Client credentials requests in your client service must include
> scope={resource}/.default. Here, {resource} is the web API that your
> app intends to call, and wishes to obtain an access token for. Issuing
> a client credentials request by using individual application
> permissions (roles) is not supported. All the app roles (application
> permissions) that have been granted for that web API are included in
> the returned access token.

The Client Credential flow is best suited for situations where you have a Deamon App that will have to authenticate and get access to some kind of a resource through a Non-Interactive way, which in sequence means that the permissions for this Deamon App have been configured and consented from a step done prior to the auth request.

The `/.default` scope can be translated as the request of the Background App that runs unattended, to get the bulk of the permissions that it has been configured with and access the resource that it asks.

In plain english, the use of the above scope in the Client Credentials flow is a convention that has to be implemented always when this flow is chosen :P.

Comment: sorry i dont follow, so which scope should I use? or do I need to change the authentication method?

Comment: If you follow the client credential flow /.default. If, on the other hand, you wish to implement a different authentication flow you can consult the below array 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added `API permissions` like below:

[image]

When I tried to generate access token with **same scope** as you via Postman using client credentials flow, I got **same error** as below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret_value>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All openid profile offline_access
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the above error, you must change your scope to https://graph.microsoft.com/.default if you are using client credentials flow.

After changing the scope, I'm able to generate **access token** successfully like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret_value>
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to call below Graph query, I got the **list of users** with display name, id and user principal name successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,id,userPrincipalName
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, change **scope** value in your code like below:

```java
List<String> scopes= Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
```